# celery.exceptions.NotRegistered when doing result -t even though inspect registered lists the task

Tags: python, celery

I'm following [Monitoring and Management](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#introduction) Guide and doing the following on my practice project:

```
celery -A celeryprac inspect registered
```

prints

```
* celeryprac.tasks.add
* celeryprac.tasks.mul
* celeryprac.tasks.xsum
```

And following up the command with the following:

```
celery -A celeryprac result -t celeryprac.tasks.add 7690f759-ad79-460e-9d56-dfac6eeebf03
```

prints the following:

```
... 
  File "/Users/alexander/.virtualenvs/celerypractice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/registry.py", line 18, in __missing__
    raise self.NotRegistered(key)
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'celeryprac.tasks.add'
```

I've tried the task names `tasks.add` and `add` with the same result. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

for me it works without task name, just put the task's UUID (celery 4.4.7):

```
celery -A celeryprac result 7690f759-ad79-460e-9d56-dfac6eeebf03
```

**EDIT**:

@AlexanderSuraphel with the `-t`, I'm getting the same error as yours. Note their comment:

> Note that you can omit the name of the task as long as the task
> doesn’t use a custom result backend.

I'm using Redis as a result backend, what are you using? did you try without result backend?

Comment: Same is true for me. I wanted to find out why the `-t` option is not working for me. Did you  try that too?

Comment: Ops, no, not near my computer now. Can I ask why do you need / want to add the task?

Comment: I was just following the guide linked above and asked a question when a document feature didn't work. It states that there is a use case for `t` too. "Note that you can omit the name of the task as long as the task doesn’t use a custom result backend.". So it will be required with custom backends.